# Typescript array of objects that has a type extending from the same interface

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array that can store objects that extend `ISlide`

```
interface ISlide {
    component: ComponentType;
}

interface ITitleSlide extends ISlide {
    title: string;
    subtitle: string;
}

interface IHeaderSlide extends ISlide {
    header: string;
}

const slides: (ITitleSlide | IHeaderSlide)[] = [
    {
        component: TitleSlide,
        title: 'Title',
        subtitle: 'Subtitle'
    },
    {
        component: HeaderSlide,
        header: 'Header'
    }
]
```

I have this code right now and I would like to add more interfaces that extend `ISlide` and update the type of the array automatically without having to write union manually. Is there a way to do this or is it only possible with classes?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w86Bdm) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame That's close to the behavior that I want but the problem is that I need to be able to use it in multiple files and pass the array between them. For more context, I'm using Svelte and passing the slides array to a component called Presentation, which takes the array and renders the slides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `type` keyword to create a union type that automatically includes all interfaces extending `ISlide`, check this out :

```
type Slide = ITitleSlide | IHeaderSlide | IAnotherSlide;

const slides: Slide[] = [
    {
        component: TitleSlide,
        title: 'Title',
        subtitle: 'Subtitle'
    },
    {
        component: HeaderSlide,
        header: 'Header'
    },
    {
        component: AnotherSlide,
        // additional properties
    }
];
```

as you see by defining the `Slide` type as a union of all interfaces that extend `ISlide`, you can simply use `Slide[]` as the type of the `slides` array!

**update**

```
interface ITitleSlide {
    component: typeof TitleSlide;
    title: string;
    subtitle: string;
}

interface IHeaderSlide {
    component: typeof HeaderSlide;
    header: string;
}

interface IAnotherSlide {
    component: typeof AnotherSlide;
    // additional properties
}

type SlideTypeMap = {
    [key: string]: Slide;
};

const slides: SlideTypeMap = {
    TitleSlide: {
        component: TitleSlide,
        title: 'Title',
        subtitle: 'Subtitle'
    },
    HeaderSlide: {
        component: HeaderSlide,
        header: 'Header'
    },
    AnotherSlide: {
        component: AnotherSlide,
        // additional properties
    }
};

type Slide = SlideTypeMap[keyof SlideTypeMap];
```

as you see,the `Slide` type is generated by using the `keyof SlideTypeMap` to retrieve all the possible keys of the `SlideTypeMap` and then accessing the corresponding values!

good luck!

Comment: Is there a way to generate the Slide union type automatically? For example, what I was trying to achieve by extending the Slide interface initially was that the array allows all types that extend the Slide interface. Something like class polymorphism but with types. I think I will end up with  about 10+ types of slides so adding the type of the slide manually to the Slide union seems a bit tedious. Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to keep a bunch of named types is interface map:

```
interface SlideTypeMap {
  ITitleSlide: ITitleSlide;
  IHeaderSlide: IHeaderSlide
}
type AnySlide = SlideTypeMap[keyof SlideTypeMap];

let slides: AnySlide[] = [...]
```

---

You may use interface merging to keep interface in multiple files at once, or use it to get list of iterfaces with their names